# pop up wiindow with notification even apllication is not running

Tags: android, notifications, popup

here is my code and I am getting my notification on time but the application is being ctrash during pop up

```
 private void showCustomPopupMenu()
{
    WindowManager windowManager2 = (WindowManager) App.getAppContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)App.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.window_popup_medicine, null);

    int LAYOUT_FLAG;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
    } else {
        LAYOUT_FLAG = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;
    }

  WindowManager.LayoutParams  params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LAYOUT_FLAG,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity=Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x=0;
        params.y=0;
    assert windowManager2 != null;
    windowManager2.addView(view, params);
    }
```

and i am getting this kisd of error like :

```
Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@46b5050 -- permission denied for window type 2038
```

I have Added all permissions :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"
    tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

please resolve this I would really appreciate your answer and thank you in advance

Comment: I solved by passing Intent to the activity I did not get adjactly as I wanted

Comment: Can we show the pop up from a foreground service even when the app is closed

Answer (score 2):

You need to have ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION permission to open/display Alert

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

  <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

set alert type of "TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY".

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
            }else{
                alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
            }
```

change your `TYPE_PHONE` with `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT`

You should also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558153/how-to-make-alertdialog-view-in-input-method-service/52902433#52902433) answer. If still you have doubt let me know.

Now when notification arrived, check this:

```
  public void notificationArrived(String myMsg){

      if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                final boolean overlayEnabled = Settings.canDrawOverlays(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);
                Global.printLog("showTaskDetailPopup==", "overlayEnabled" + overlayEnabled);

                if (!overlayEnabled) return;
            }

  new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.window_popup_medicine);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);

                TextView tv_msg = dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg);

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);
                    } else {
                            dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
                    }
                    dialog.show();
                }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: @bugfreerammohan i also added refer link if you have any doubts with this

Comment: I am using this with notification and still, I am getting the same error

Comment: because you must have overlay permission before this dialog open. So first take overlay permission. refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558153/how-to-make-alertdialog-view-in-input-method-service/52902433#52902433

Comment: windowManager2.addView(view, params); getting error in this line with same error 2019-09-26 14:23:10.035 12825-12825/com.kulsoft.care4cute E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kulsoft.care4cute, PID: 12825
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@191cd10 -- permission denied for window type 2038

Comment: first let me know your overlay permission enabled or not?? because i am also showing popup when notification arrived using this

Comment: I have added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_OVERLAY_WINDOW" />
 and   <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

Comment: also this :     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200001/discussion-between-bhoomika-patel-and-bugfreerammohan).

Comment: Can we show the pop up from a foreground service even when the app is closed