# Andorid: show Dialog over other apps

Tags: android

I have a question: Can I show alert Dialog over another application?

I want to notify the user when he received a message. Shows standard notification is not enough. But when I create an AlertDialog, it can't be displayed over other applications.

```
  private void showAlertDialog(View view, Order order, Order oldOrder) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_extra_info, null);
        builder.setView(content);
        final EditText etKmCounter = content.findViewById(R.id.et_km_counter);
        final EditText etMotoHourCounter = content.findViewById(R.id.et_counter_moto_hour);
        final AlertDialog ad = builder.show();

        Button btnSave = content.findViewById(R.id.save);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (StringUtils.isEmpty(etKmCounter.getText().toString()) || StringUtils.isEmpty(etMotoHourCounter.getText().toString())) {
                openFillDataAlertDialog();
            } else {
                ad.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at push notifications

Comment: I think what you need is a [float window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731445/floating-app-on-android-windowed-app)

Answer (score 3):

You need to have `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` permission to display Alert dialog when your app is not open or if you want to show dialog on other app too.

Check this Link, I mentioned all with details here:
[pop up wiindow with notification even apllication is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112575/pop-up-wiindow-with-notification-even-apllication-is-not-running/58112860#58112860)

[How to make AlertDialog view in Input method Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558153/how-to-make-alertdialog-view-in-input-method-service/52902433#52902433)

Comment: @kpokrywja try this solution, and let me know if you have any question related to this.