# How to display the dialog from ime service in android programatically?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, dialog, ime

Can anyone help me to display the custom dialog from the ime service. I have searched lot of things on the internet but nothing got usefull to popup the dialog from the ime service.

I'm using below code to display dialog :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);
builder.setView(view);
builder.setCancelable(false);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

But I'm getting below error :

2021-09-05 21:35:35.574 14533-14533/com.xyz W/System.err: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040003 a=-1}
2021-09-05 21:35:35.575 14533-14533/com.xyz W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f040003 a=-1}

W/System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:761)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7282)
W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7463)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.(RelativeLayout.java:1253)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1086)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1085)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:860)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)

**Please help me to show dialog from the ime service**

Below is xml file for the layout of dialog :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/action"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_translate_24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/texts"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/ten_dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ScrollView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="@dimen/ten_dp"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
                </ScrollView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="45dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/ten_dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:text="@string/close" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please let me know if there any solution for it.

Comment: My guess is that you will need to start an activity rather than show a dialog. Note that activities can have a theme that styles them like a dialog.

Comment: @CommonsWare You don't, if the keyboard is visible.  You can do it via the window token of the keyboard's view.  Or at least you could 5 years ago, haven't written a keyboard since then.

Comment: This seems like an error in your xml, given the trace.  Some value is invalid when it tries to fetch it.

Comment: @CommonsWare  I already did it with dialog theme for that activity but it doesn't worked for me.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have also added my xml layout file in this question. I doesn't found any problem in that. Can you please look into it and help me to show the dialog?. Thanks

Comment: @GabeSechan Can you please look into it? Thanks.

Comment: @ChiragPrajapati The problem is in getLayoutDimension, so its in either a layout_width or layout_height parameter.  My suspicion is this one:          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize".  That probably was supposed to be a style attribute.

Comment: @GabeSechan So, You mean I should use "56dp" instead of "?attr/actionBarSize" for layout_hight right? And thanks for the reply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236816/discussion-between-chirag-prajapati-and-gabe-sechan).

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It's very simple just use below code :

```
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, new FrameLayout(context));

PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);
popup.setContentView(dialogView);
// If you need the PopupWindow to dismiss when when touched outside
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());

popup.showAtLocation(mInputView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

Button btnCancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
btnCancel.setOnClickListener(v -> popup.dismiss());
```

Thank you. Enjoy the code. :)